# design pattern for initializing algorithms which each accept different parameters

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm looking to redesign a library I have.
Currently I have a set of algorithms which don't relate to eachother in any way.

My goal is to have all concrete algorithms implement an interface which will consist roughly of `Init()` and `Run(In,Out)` so that I could execute them in the following fashion:

```
void Process()
{
    // IAlgotrithm* algX = new CAlgX(); X:{A,B,C}
    IAlgorithm* algs[] = { algA, algB, algC }; 
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        algs[i]->Init(...);
        algs[i]->Run(In,Out);     
    }
 }
```

The problem is, currently each algorithm accepts a different struct as its input parameter.
For instance, `CAlgA` has a method `Init(CAlgAParameter param)` where `CAlgAParameter` is a struct with fields specific to AlgA. Each algorithm has it's own structure which consists of totally different fields of different types.
What is the best way to approach this ?

One option I could think of is having a map with all parameters relevant to all the algorithms, and delegate the job of initializing the input structure to the algorithm. That is, the client of the algorithm won't know what the specific input structure looks like- it will be the algorithms job to create its input structure based on all the global parameters in the map. I don't love this idea because it can't be checked in compile-time and too error-prone.

What would be the best way to approach this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to define `IAlgotrithm::Init` in a generic way ? What is the type of `algA`, `algB` ?

Comment: why not to construct algorithms with parameters? What is the goal of uniform initialization? Seems that code responsible for _uniform_ initialization/running should not know about init details.

Comment: @iammilind Yes, i would like to define Init in a generic way. algX are concrete classes that derive from IAlgorithm.
@user396672 I can construct them with certain parameters, but I need to give them specific parameters each time they run

Answer (score 5):

Why not initialize during construction, and simply call `Run()` in the loop? Hence at construction you can make it the user's responsibility to provide the correct configuration for a given algorithm, i.e.

```
IAlgorithm* algs[] = { new CAlgA(CAlgAParameter(...)), new CAlgB(CAlgBParameter(...)), new CAlgC(CAlgCParameter(...)) }; 

//loop
```

Use exceptions to handle incorrect configuration to the algorithms.

Comment: The "init" parameters change each time the pipe of algorithms is run. I can initialize them like you mentioned, but I still need a way to call Init in a generic way every iteration

Comment: Which iteration? Each time the pipe is called or each time an algorithm in the pipe is called? If the former, is constructing each time too heavy weight? If latter, why is this needed if init happens during construction?

Comment: You have Init parameters, and Control parameters. The algorithms are created once, with the Init parameters. Then each time before invoking `Run`, the Control parameters need to be set.

Comment: Still don't see it - `Run()` is called on each algo in the pipeline, why not pass these control parameters in the construction too? Or are they modified by each algo as it's run? And therefore the subsequent algo requires the modified parameters? None of this is in your original question...

Comment: Yes. The control parameters are modified each time and thus need to be set each time time the algo is run. I didn't want to go into too many details in the question, therefore did not write about the difference of the type of parameters. But, it is understood from the question that you need to call `Init` each time before running the algo.

Answer (score 0):

For static parameters, which will not be changed by any algorithm, constructor based initialization is fine.  The control parameters that must be supplied for each run of the algorithm can be specified by an interface (or abstract classes with all abstract methods) for each algorithm.

```
public class IAlg1ControlParams {
public: 
    virtual ~IAlg1ControlParams () {}
    virtual int getParam1() = 0;
    virtual void setParam2(char val) = 0;
}
```

This will keep your algorithm footprint as small as possible for each call.  These interfaces will also be useful for testing your algorithms, as you only need to provide an implementation of the two interfaces in your tests, rather than some large map of parameters with string keys.  You could do even better using a Mocking Framework like [Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/).

```
public void WhenInputIs10_Algorithm1SetsParam2Tob() {
    Alg1 alg1 = new Alg1("Test data", 10);
    IAlg1ControlParams context = new MockAlg1ControlParams(10);
    alg1.Run(context);
    assert(context.getParam2() == 'b');
}
```

You can then have one context or state object that implements the interfaces for each set  of algorithms that need to be executed.  This will ensure that you have compile time checking that the parameter fields and methods exist.  Also, if you need data to flow from one algorithm to another, using the same context object will ensure that the updated data is provided to the later algorithms in your pipeline.

```
public class AlgSet1Context: public IAlg1Context, public IAlg2Context...
```

Within each algorithm you will need to validate that the values in the control parameters.  I would recommend using the template method pattern here, so you have a base business rule that provides a non-virtual implementation of `Run(ControlParams)` and calls two protected virtual methods `Verify(ControlParams)` and `Execute(ControlParams)`.  This will ensure that all developers who implement new algorithms at a later date know that they must verify the control parameters.